# Whay facebook FQL search my group joint is null...?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I tried to search groups with fql, which I'm in. And I use fql:

```
SELECT page_id,name,pic_square FROM page WHERE page_id in (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me()) and can_post = 'true' and strpos(lower(name),'Online')>=0
```

but the result is always nothing

Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you receive if you'll remove the last condition `and strpos(lower(name),'Online')>=0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course null, because 'Online' O is Capital letter but your strpos is compare with lower(name),that  means even though you have a group name called "Online", you are compare as strpos(online,'Online') which ALWAYS return -1, and then >=0 goal is impossible to achive.